# CRM Outlook Client throws error when navigating on Opportunity Related Entities

Tags: javascript, exception, dynamics-crm-2011, outlook-addin

If a navigate on Outlook for CRM2011 Client, offline or online, two different error message appears randomly after closing the opportunity form, after I clicked in the Related section.

It does not matter on which related item I click, it happens on every single one.

First Error:

```
   <Message>Object doesn't support this action</Message>
   <Line>1</Line>
   <URL>/_static/_common/scripts/PageLoader.js?ver=24974061</URL>
   <PageURL>/main.aspx?etc=3&extraqs=%3fetc%3d3%26id%3d%257bED62CF68-7336-E311-B2FB-00155DCE57C4%257d%26pagemode%3diframe%26preloadcache%3d1382347798987&pagetype=entityrecord</PageURL>
   <Function>executeAction(action)</Function>
   <CallStack>
    <Function>executeAction(action)</Function>
   </CallStack>
  </ScriptErrorDetails>
  <ClientInformation>
   <BrowserUserAgent>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; MSNIE9A; Microsoft Outlook 14.0.6126)</BrowserUserAgent>
   <BrowserLanguage>en-US</BrowserLanguage>
   <SystemLanguage>de-DE</SystemLanguage>
   <UserLanguage>de-DE</UserLanguage>
   <ScreenResolution>1920x1200</ScreenResolution>
   <ClientName>Outlook Laptop - Online</ClientName>
```

Second Error:

```
ScriptErrorDetails>
   <Message>Object doesn't support this action</Message>
   <Line>1</Line>
   <URL>/_static/_controls/ribbon/ribbon.js?ver=24974061</URL>
   <PageURL>/main.aspx?etc=3&extraqs=%3fetc%3d3%26id%3d%257bED62CF68-7336-E311-B2FB-00155DCE57C4%257d%26pagemode%3diframe%26preloadcache%3d1382347474700&pagetype=entityrecord</PageURL>
   <Function>anonymous(){try{$$t_4.$8D_3($p0,$p1)}catch($v_1){if($v_1.number!==-2146823277)throw$v_1}}</Function>
   <CallStack>
    <Function>anonymous(){try{$$t_4.$8D_3($p0,$p1)}catch($v_1){if($v_1.number!==-2146823277)throw$v_1}}</Function>
   </CallStack>
  </ScriptErrorDetails>
  <ClientInformation>
   <BrowserUserAgent>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; MSNIE9A; Microsoft Outlook 14.0.6126)</BrowserUserAgent>
   <BrowserLanguage>en-US</BrowserLanguage>
   <SystemLanguage>de-DE</SystemLanguage>
   <UserLanguage>de-DE</UserLanguage>
   <ScreenResolution>1920x1200</ScreenResolution>
   <ClientName>Outlook Laptop - Online</ClientName>
```

I have tried to disable all custom JS code on the opportunity form, but the error still appears.

Are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

In our structure we got JS contract and Controller for each entity. 
After this Design we used Enable Rules on the contrat which calls the real enable rule in the Controller.

For some reasons the Controller might not been loaded at the Moment when the enable rule is fired. So we got the strange ribbon.js error.

After moving the enable rule in the contract everything works fine.